# win32con.MB_YESNO and win32con.MB_OK

Tags: python, popup

I'm trying out pop-up message windows and am not having much luck. I want to ask the user  if certain files exist before beginning a process then instruct the user to download the files if they don't already exist. I opted to throw up a message box that asks if the files exist using the win32api.MessageBox / win32con.MB_YESNO functions, then if the answer is 'no' another message box using win32con.MB_OK.

The script runs and a message box appears with the  yes/no  buttons, but nothing happens if you click either button. I actually have to click the 'Close' button on the main script dialog before only the 'no' button will work in the message box. But then I get a process canceled by user error.

While I'm sure that there is another way to do this, now that I've started down this path I'm determined to figure it out. Anybody got any ideas? I think I've checked every link on 7 pages of Google results and still have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
import arcpy, win32com.client, win32api, win32con
from win32con import MB_OK, MB_YESNO

result = win32api.MessageBox(0, "Do the files exist?.", "Shapefiles", win32con.MB_YESNO);
if result == win32con.IDYES:
    pass
else:
    win32api.MessageBox(0, "Please downloaded the windswath and forecast point & lines from HURREVAC and restart the script.", "HURREVAC Shapefiles", win32con.MB_OK);

arcpy.AddMessage("did this work?")
```

Comment: This should go on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem using the code above (Win7 x64, Python 2.7.3 32-bit).  I don't have `arcpy` so I replaced the call to `arcpy.AddMessage` with a `print` statement.